# Pyinstaller missing SqlAlchemy dlls

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyside, pyinstaller

I am using Pyinstaller to compile Python to a standalone executable. The sourcecode includes modules PySide and SqlAlchemy. The dist .exe that PyInstaller creates runs OK, but when I run commands that access the database I get this error code in the command prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "clipper_tree.py", line 1907, in add_tree
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\sql\operators.py", line 304, in __eq__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 175, in operate
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\sql\operators.py", line 304, in __eq__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\orm\properties.py", line 270, in operate
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\sql\annotation.py", line 95, in __eq__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\sql\operators.py", line 304, in __eq__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 686, in operate
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\sql\operators.py", line 304, in __eq__
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\sql\type_api.py", line 62, in operate
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 964, in __getattr__
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 962, in __getattr__
ImportError: Could not resolve module sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator
```

While compiling, the command prompt output a few warnings about not being able to find "hidden DLLs" relating to sql alchemy. It said it was removing sqlalchemy/test files in response. Any help here would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 14):

i had a same issue earlier.. resolves this problem by importing sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator on my main program..

Comment: That worked. I think one could also prevent this error by defining a hidden import for sqlalchemy.

Comment: how does one define a hidden import?

Comment: @user1111652 You can add the module name as a string to the hidden param of the Analysis initializer, which is included in your pyinstaller spec file. Note spec files are perfectly valid Python code, don't fear breaking anything.

Answer (score 1):

As @fredpi says you can add the module to the `hiddenimports` parameter of the `Analysis` initializer in the .spec file of the python file your trying to compile. Like so: `hiddenimports=['sqlalchemy.sql.default_comparator']`

Make sure you pass the .spec file when you run pyinstaller, or it will overwrite the .spec file and your changes will be lost. For example: `pyinstaller --onefile myscript.spec`